# How to get the class that raised an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I have an error class:

```
module Error
  class Base < StandardError
    def initialize
      binding.pry
    end
  end
end
```

I raised the error from a controller:

```
raise Error::Base
```

I want to get the class name or the file name where the error was raised. Is there any way to do this?

The `backtrace`, `cause`, and `backtrace_locations` return `nil`.

Comment: What is `base`?

Comment: @sawa I think the intention was `raise Error::Base`

Comment: @engineersmnky You may be right. If that is the case, then the OP is too sloppy.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's typing mistake. `raise Error::Base`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're grabbing the exception while it's being built, before it has actually been raised -- that's why it's not fully populated.

If you really need to capture execution right there, you could use [`caller`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) to see the *current* stack trace, just as you could in any other method. Until it's been raised, you won't get much benefit from the exception.

Comment: Oh, I see what I need, but it seems I have to do some logic to find out the right place.

Thank you!